# Are the children of Python data classes always data classes themselves?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-decorators, python-dataclasses

Suppose I create a parent class and a child class in **Python** like so:

```py
@dataclass
class MyParent:
    an_attribute: str = "Hello!"
    another_attribute: str = "Dave!"

@dataclass
class MyChild(MyParent):
    another_attribute: str = "Steve!"
```

Then, clearly, both `MyParent` and `MyChild` will be data classes.

But, what happens if I use the following syntax to create `MyChild` instead?

```py
class MyChild(MyParent):
    another_attribute: str = "Steve!"
```

Testing on my own machine suggests that, even with the latter syntax, `MyChild` will also be a data class. But are the children of data classes **always** data classes themselves? Are there any pitfalls to the latter approach? Is the `@dataclass` decorator essentially redundant in the definition of the child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the decorator again is [required](https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/#inheritance). Without it, the fields of the child class are not created properly.

```
>>> @dataclass
... class MyParent:
...     an_attribute: str = "Hello!"
...     another_attribute: str = "Dave!"
... 
... class MyChild(MyParent):
...     another_attribute: str = "Steve!"
... 
>>> MyChild().another_attribute  # returns the incorrect default
'Dave!'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dataclass` magic is not triggered for the non-dataclass version of `My_Child`, although it will inherit the special dataclass attributes (`__dataclass_fields__` etc) from `My_Parent`, but *only for the parent's attributes*

Try this:

```
class MyChild(MyParent):
    another_attribute: str = "Steve!"
    yet_another_attribute : str = "Mickey!"
```

You will see that `yet_another_attribute` is a *class* member, not an *instance* one